# java storing output from file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I have a question on how to store output from a file into an array. In my case, I am trying to store all the date in a file into an array. For the way that I did it, the compiler complains "not a statement". How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code (the line of error is preceded by backslashes):

```
double token[] = new double[9];

            File filename = new File("/Users/timothylee/gravity1.txt");

            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(filename);

            while(inFile.hasNext()){
               //////////////// token[] = inFile.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(token);
            }
            inFile.close();
```

If needed, here is the file:

```
gravity1.txt:
      3.70
      8.87
      9.79
      3.70
      24.78
      10.44
      8.86
      11.13
      0.61
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double token[] = new double[9];

int i = 0;
while(inFile.hasNext()){
    token[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(token);
    i++;
}
inFile.close();
```

This is assuming the file only has 9 lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
        ArrayList<Double> token = new ArrayList<Double>();

        File filename = new File("/Users/timothylee/gravity1.txt");

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(filename);

        while(inFile.hasNext()){
            token.add(inFile.nextDouble());
        }
        inFile.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(token));
```

Just use an ArrayList, dont make your life harder as it is. ;) This also makes it way more flexible, as it doesnt matter how many data/lines are in your file.

Comment: Better keep the answer simple and use as much of OP's code as possible for questions like this

Comment: @Yitzchak thats what I actually did...? 2 lines changed in code and 2 sentences as an answer ;)

Comment: The code OP used could almost have been c++ and was written in a way he understands. all that really needed to be added was a variable for the array to iterate over. Just my teaching style (and still being somewhat a novice myself) :)

Comment: Sure, its also necessary that someone showed him the way the tried too. But as you can see many ppl here posted that answer already.. so showing alternative approaches is rounding up the whole teaching thing here :D (And I would also feel not comfortable giving him a solution that I would never realize like that in the case of storing file content in an object)

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning anything to your token array, which is why you are getting the "not a statement" error. You need to tell Java *where* to put the next double like this:

`double token[] = new double[9];

            File filename = new File("/Users/timothylee/gravity1.txt");`

```
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(filename);
        int i = 0;
        while(inFile.hasNext()){
           token[i] = inFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(token);
           i++;
        }
        inFile.close();
```

Answer (score -2):

This would be simpler in Java 8 with map. Here is the Java 7 version:

```
    File filename = new File("/Users/timothylee/gravity1.txt");

    List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            doubleList.add(Double.parseDouble(line))
        }
    }

    double[] doubles = new double[doubleList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < doubleList.size(); i++) {
        doubles[i] = doubleList.get(i);
    }
```