# store values from a file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I want to store the values from a .txt document into an array. I already tried this [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549272/java-storing-output-from-file-into-an-array) and non of them worked. I want to store the values on an array because I will use that array in future methods to get the average, sum, etc.

This is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class example{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("integers.txt"));

int counter = 0;
while(input.hasNext()){

  int numbers = input.nextInt();
  counter++;
}
int[] array = new int[counter];
for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
  System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

My output is:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

And it should be the numbers on the file:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

Any help will be much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger to identify where it is not doing what you expect?  Hint: You read in the numbers but didn't save them while you were reading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to store it in a list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("integers.txt"));

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();

    while (input.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The sum method could be like this:

```
private static int sum(List<Integer> numbers) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int number : numbers) {
        total += number;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Cheers Mate.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing out the array, you need to actually read the file into the array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("integers.txt"));

    int counter = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        counter++;
    }
    int[] array = new int[counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Stream and then converting to array is simple 2 lines of code.
1 line to print the results.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
         Stream<String> streamString = Files.lines(Paths.get("integers.txt"));
         int[] intArray = streamString.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
         Arrays.stream(intArray).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```